# Tomcat installation directory for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have installed tomcat8 using `apt-get` and it was installed properly.

I have to integrate tomcat with eclipse but when I provide installation directory as `/usr/share/tomcat8`, it says

```
config file is corrupt/missing
```

[image: configuration corrupt/missing]

And when I specify the path as `/etc/tomcat8`, eclipse gives this error:

[image: Unknown version of tomcat]

How can I specify the correct installation directory?

Comment: after install with `sudo apt install tomcat9`  this path did  worked for me`/usr/share/tomcat9`

Answer (score 0):

Probably no longer interesting for the questioner but maybe for others looking at this question: The solution for me was to use the "Download and Install..." button offered by eclipse itself. Marked it in the screenshot of the question:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Sistem: ubuntu 18.04
- eclipse 2019-12(4.14.0)
- apache tomcat 9.0.16-3ubuntu0.18.04.1
- Eclipse was installed with the official Eclipse-installer app for linux [eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2019-12/R/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz)
- tomcat was installed by `sudo apt install tomcat9`

---

If you do not know the path, you could do the following steps:

```
$ whereis tomcat9
```

The above command returns some directories or links.
Now check or list any of those outputs directories with `ll` command
Remember that we need the path that has a bin directory

[image]

Then `/usr/share/tomcat9` should work but one of the problem is about directory **PERMISSIONS**.

If you are a new Linux user you must remember that directories have permissions as `read, write, execute`, etc another concept is `owner` of files e.g. `you, groups, others`.
Eclipse doesn't have permission to write in the above path, you can manually find all the directories and create `links` but if you don't want to waste time scratching that , the best option is download tomcat9 from the official website create a new directory and decompress there. That' why I think [the majority of tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804) always download tomcat from the official website.